# Can I undo a terminal shortcut?

Tags: terminal

I accidentally click <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> in the terminal and removed output that had been generated over a week.

Is there any way to undo this?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean - Cmd-L in Terminal isn't mapped to any shortcut by default and we have no idea how your output was being generated.

Comment: @Allan it is mapped by default to "Clear To Previous Mark".

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek - I can't find it on mine (I haven't changed anything) and it doesn't do anything.  But if it's "clear", then it's gone.

Comment: @Allan It's in the Edit menu, forth menu item group from the top

Comment: @patrix - My bad...been using iTerm so long I forgot it wasn't Terminal.

Comment: Basically if cmd-Z does not work - but this is the wroing way to capture output - pipe the output to a file

Comment: @Mark Yeah, I learned my lesson. My script now outputs to a file as well.